# Json response for 404/503 errors

Tags: java, rest, dropwizard

When I use `404` response code Dropwizard returns custom html code (even when `Accept` header equals `application/json`).

Controller method:

```
if (o == null) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
} else {
    return Response.ok(o).build();
}
```

Dropwizard response:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /abc/1. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
...                                               

</body>
</html>
```

How can I customize return body for `404`, `503` response codes (and etc) to return JSON?

ps
I have already implemented custom exceptions mappers. But I don't want to use exceptions for this task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few days I decided to `throw new com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException()` and process it by my custom `WebApplicationExceptionMapper`.

Answer (score 5):

you should use the type and entity methods of the response builder.

something like:

```
return Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .entity(error).build();
```

where error is serializable to json.

Comment: My class has `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` annotation. Why is this not working?

Comment: try adding the entity part which will add the body content

Comment: yes, adding `.entity(error)` fixed this problem... But I solved this problem other way

Comment: how do you solve the problem with the class annotation? @fedor.belov